# Unity make instantiated object toggle appear or disappear

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, toggle, instantiation

So I have a simple project where I make a game board out of multiple squares, and it has a grid that can be toggled on or off.

Unfortunately, it does not work that way. Here is my board manager code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BoardHandle {
    [RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
    public class BoardManager : MonoBehaviour { 

        //2d list that represents the board
        List<List<GameObject>> board = new List<List<GameObject>> ();

        //Gamebjects import
        public GameObject GrassTile;
        public GameObject Grid;

        //UI buttons import
        public Toggle GridToggle;

        //Miscellanious variables that could be edited in inspector
        public int rows;
        public int cols;
        public float tileWidth;
        public float tileHeight;


        void Start() {

            GrassTile.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (tileWidth, tileHeight, 0f);
            Grid.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (tileWidth, tileHeight, 0f);

            //Adds all of the stuff to the game board
            for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
                board.Add (new List<GameObject> ());
                for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
                    board [x].Add (GrassTile);
                }
            }


            //Makes board bits all go to the screen
            for (int x = 0; x < board.Count; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < board[x].Count; y++) {

                    //Makes the grid. And it stays there currently until the game ends.
                    Instantiate (Grid, 
                                 new Vector3 (x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight, 0),
                                 Quaternion.identity); 

                    //This is the actual board, filled with grass tiles. I wnat to keep this.
                    Instantiate (board [x] [y], 
                                 new Vector3 (x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight, 0), 
                                 Quaternion.identity);
                }
            }
        }


        void Update() {

        }


    }
}
```

My game programming experience is from Pygame. In Pygame, the background has to constantly regenerate over itself, so if I want to make the grid disappear, all I need to do is stop blitting it once per frame, and a frame later it is gone. In unity, since objects can move without having to regenerate the background in the code, the grid stays after just one instantiate. I just want to know a way that when GridToggle.isOn is true, the grid is instantiated and will stay there until GridToggle.isOn is false, when the grid will no longer be there until it is toggled on again. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Unity GameObjects can be deactivated and components can be disabled.

If a GameObject is deactivated it is considered as "not there". If you just want to disable rendering, you could alternatively just disable the renderer component of the tiles. Sounds like the first option is what you want.

Deactivating a GameObject also deactivates its child GameObjects. To disable the board and its contents, I would suggest having the instantiated objects as children of the board. You can do this through the transform of the GameObject:

```
instantiatedGameObject.transform.parent = this.transform;
```

Since you are using Toggle, you could add an event listener to it:

```
GridToggle.onValueChanged.AddListener((value) => this.SetActive(value));
```

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. But I wonder, how can I  disable the renderer remotely from another script. The grid is managed from a separate script, and it is a prefab.

Comment: So instead of the Toggle you want to control it with another script? If you have a reference to the GameObject with the BoardHandle you can simply deactivate it from the other script.